# Slowness switching TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, tabitem

I have a TabControl with multiple TabItems. Ocasianally I experience slow loading times switching from one tab to another. First thought was the service, however the application doesn't seem to call the service when switching the tab.

```xml
<TabControl Visibility="{Binding MenuVisible}" Name="MenuControl" Grid.Row="1" >

<TabItem Header="Business Rules Alerts" >

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="250" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ContentControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="GraphAlertsRegion" Margin="0" />

        <!-- Grid for UserListRegion and EventListRegion -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- EventList region -->
            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="EAlertsListRegion" Margin="0" />

        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Business Rules">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=".5*" />
            <RowDefinition Height=".5*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="BusinessRulesListRegion" Margin="0" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ScrollViewer  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="BusinessRulesWizardRegion" Margin="0" />
            </ScrollViewer>

        </Grid>

</TabItem>

</TabControl>
```

Is there a way to improve the performance? 
In particular,

```
<ContentControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="GraphAlertsRegion" Margin="0" />
```

is a treeView plus some graphs ( `<charting:Chart.Series>` ) which is the slower tab . I have made sure that the code doesn't call to the service when we switch to that tab. So what else could be the reason of the delay?

Comment: Take a look at your control loaded event handlers if you have any.

Answer (score 3):

This is weird standard behaviour of TabControl - it is unload items whilst switching, so you have to extend it slightly to keep cached TabItems whilst switching, see more details with an example in this article: [Keeping the WPF Tab Control from destroying its children](http://eric.burke.name/dotnetmania/2009/04/26/22.09.28)

Comment: How you know? Didi you tried this already? I've encounteret the same issue whilst using TabCOntrol first time and this helped me. Perhaps you observing issue which not related to TabControl itself but somehow related to your code?